# (Не)заверена. Слитно или раздельно?

Tags: слитно-раздельно

Копия документа (не)заверена. Слитно или раздельно?
Спасибо!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

**Раздельно:** *копия документа **не заверена**.*

============

См. http://orthographia.ru/orfografia.php?sid=78#pp78 :

> **§ 146.** Отрицание ***не*** пишется раздельно в следующих случаях.
>
> **1.** Со всеми формами глаголов (кроме полных причастий; о них см. §
> 150):
>
> <...>
>
> б) **с краткими формами причастий**,
> напр.: *не использован, не
> накрахмалено, не откупорена...*